# Authentication required pop-up when loading JNLP for internal website

Tags: java, authentication, required

Recently we started to upgrade our clients from Java 6u31 to 8u121.

Here we see an impact on our internal web application written in Java.

Client(s) connects to a web-server which has the JNLP and JARs locally.

However now with the new Java 8u121 we get a pop-up from java : Authentication required.
We can click on cancel and the Java app will load but this is not acceptable for our users.

Is this a Java problem or a Proxy problem?

Comment: It's unclear what the pop-up triggers. And does not seem to be Java related.

Answer (score 1):

We started to do a trace with wire-shark to see what happens when the Java pop-up "authentication required" occurs. Here we could see that our proxy server blocks a global-sign site to validate a certificate. Here we made an exception for that site. Now we have no issue anymore and the pop-up is not occurring anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent that authentication window by setting the property **deployment.security.authenticator**  value to false in the deployment.properties

> Normally Plug-in and Web Start install an Authenticator to handle
>   communication with Authenticating web pages or Authenticating proxies.
>   This is the default behavior (true). This option can be used to turn
>   the normal behavior off if, for example, an application communicates
>   directly with an authenticating web page and needs to install its own
>   Authenticator.

Location of the deployment.properties

**in Windows** - \LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties

**in Linux** - ${user.home}/.java/deployment/deployment.properties

**in OS X** - ~/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties